# Найти в списке смежные вложенные списки и объединить их в новый список

Tags: python, list

Помогите разобраться.
Имеется основной список со вложенными списками:

```
a = [[1, 6], [5, 10], [6, 7], [9, 10]]
```

Необходимо сравнить каждый вложенный список друг с другом на наличие общего элемента и на выходе получить новый список в формате:

```
b = [[1, 6, 7], [5, 9, 10]]
```

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: у вас идеальный случай в примере, а так очень много "но", если в 3 или более пересекается хотя бы по одному, что делать?

Comment: Нужно ли соблюдать порядок следования элементов?

Comment: Вложенных списков в списке "а"  может быть намного больше, но всегда они состоят из 2-х элементов и пересекаются(если пересекаются) только по одному из этих значений с остальными. А список  "b" не ограничен по количеству элементов.

Comment: Порядок следования не имеет значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробывал такой вариант:

```
import numpy
from itertools import groupby

array = numpy.array([[1, 6], [5, 10], [6, 7], [9, 10]]).astype(numpy.uint8)
res_array = []
for i in array:
    array_i = numpy.array([]).astype(numpy.uint8)
    for j in array:
        if len(numpy.intersect1d(i, j)) > 0:
            array_j = numpy.unique(numpy.concatenate([i, j]))
            array_i = numpy.unique(numpy.concatenate([array_i, array_j]))
    res_array.append(list(array_i))
res_array = sorted(res_array)
res_array = [i for i, _ in groupby(res_array)]
```

Результат:

```
[[1, 6, 7], [5, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 6], [5, 10], [6, 7], [9, 10]]


res = []
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for j in a[i:]:
        if np.intersect1d(a[i], j).size > 0:
            tmp = set(a[i]+ j)
            if len(tmp) > 2:
                res.append([*tmp])
```

получаем `res`:

```
[[1, 6, 7], [9, 10, 5]]
```